# Managing page-specific stylesheets and javascript files with Rails 3 application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to keep the application layout in my Rails 3 app for the stylesheets and javascript files I use most frequently (application.js, jquery, style, etc.). However there are plugins I'm using on certain pages and want to include those stylesheets/javascripts properly. For example, I'm looking to use [slides](http://slidesjs.com/) only on my homepage. If my application layout is like the one below, what's the best way to include page-specific files?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css" media="screen and (min-width:481px)">
  <!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css" media="all"><![endif]-->
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
</head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```